# Display all the values inside an array using a button

Tags: javascript, arrays

The function will display all the even numbers between starting number and ending number based on the step value.
For example, if I enter 1, 20, and 3.
I should have 4, 10, and 16 as even number.

I need to push all the numbers inside evenNum array into #result span.
Currently it seems to only display the last even number inside the array.

Further more, if I would like to display all even number in vertical line, how do I do it?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wgwaey

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Sample</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container">

        <label>Starting Number: </label>
        <input id="startingNum" type="text">
        <br>
        <label>Ending Number: </label>
        <input id="endingNum" type="text">
        <br>
        <label>Step: </label>
        <input id="step" type="text">
        <br>
        <button onclick="playButton()" id="play">Display Evens</button>

    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <p>Here are the even numbers between <span id="startNum"></span> and <span id="endNum"></span> by <span id="stepNum"></span>'s:</p>
        <span id="result"></span>
    </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
<script>
        function playButton(){
            run();
        }
        function run(){
            var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("startingNum").value);
            var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("endingNum").value);
            var z = parseInt(document.getElementById("step").value);
            document.getElementById("startNum").innerHTML = x;
            document.getElementById("endNum").innerHTML = y;
            document.getElementById("stepNum").innerHTML = z;
            var evenNum = [];
            while (x < y){    
                if (x%2 == 0){
                    evenNum.push(x);
                }
                x += z;
                for (var i = 0; i<evenNum.length; i++){
                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = evenNum[i];
                }
            }
        }          
</script>
```

Comment: You could just dynamically create a table with however many rows you need (each containing one cell in this case) and put the values into those cells. That'd create a simple vertical presentation. Search for "create table with JavaScript" and a number of examples will pop up. Some people may tell you "don't use tables", I'd ignore that as snobbery (look at the source of this page, it uses tables). They're widely used, stable everywhere including mobile, easy to manipulate with CSS, and braindead simple, ideal for a beginner to learn with.

Comment: Please note that if a user enters 0 or a negative number in for the step, the application will have an infinite while loop. You really should throw a check around that and prompt the user to enter a positive number from 1 to n

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is that doing `parseInt()` on an empty string will return NaN. If you replace `parseInt` with `Math.round(Number([your string value here]))` You will not get NaN, and your numbers will still be integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
for (var i = 0; i<evenNum.length; i++){
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = evenNum[i];
}
```

You need to move this out of the `while` loop and change it to

```
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += ' ' + evenNum[i];
                                             // ^ add to existing
```

Or, more simply, delete the `for` loop and put this after the `while` loop:

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = evenNum.join(' ');
```

Answer (score 2):

The mistake above is that you're continuously reseting the result's inner HTML, so the last element of even num is the only one displayed. Also, you don't need to be updating result inside of your `while` loop, you can do it once you're done looking. Try this out!

```
function playButton(){
    run();
}
function run(){
    var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("startingNum").value);
    var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("endingNum").value);
    var z = parseInt(document.getElementById("step").value);
    document.getElementById("startNum").innerHTML = x;
    document.getElementById("endNum").innerHTML = y;
    document.getElementById("stepNum").innerHTML = z;
    var evenNum = [];
    while (x < y){    
        if (x%2 == 0){
            evenNum.push(x);
        }        
        x += z;  
    }
    for (var i = 0; i<evenNum.length; i++){
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "<p>" + evenNum[i] + "</p>";
    }
}
```