# JavaScript: Number Sequence with a For Loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, sequence

JS:
    function myarray (){

```
}
  var starting=document.getElementById("starting");
  var ending=document.getElementById("ending");
  var step=document.getElementById("step");
  var results=document.getElementById("myarray")

  if (i>=0){
    var result=starting
  }

for (var starting>=0; myarray<=ending; i+=step)
  document.writeln(myarray[i+=step]){
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="results">Here are the even numbers between "startingnumber" and "endingnumber" by "step"&nnsp's


    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
      <title>A Web Page</title>
     </head>

     <script src="Guild_Practice.js"></script>

     <style media="screen">
    table {
      width:40%;
    }

    .titles {
      text-align: right;
      color: green;
      font-family: arial;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    caption {
      font-size: 32px;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-family: cursive;
      color: red;
    }
    .displayevens {
      text-align: center;
      padding-top: 10px;
    }










    }

     </style>

     <body>
      <table>
        <caption>Sample</caption>
      <form>
        <tr>
          <!--Starting Number Line with Form -->
          <td class="titles">Starting Number</td>
          <td class="align-left"><input type="text" id="starting"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <!-- Ending Number Line with Form -->
          <td class="titles">Ending Number</td>
          <td class="align-left"><input type="text" id="ending"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <!-- Step Line with Form -->
          <td class="titles">Step</td>
          <td class="align-left"><input type="text" id="step"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <!-- Button covered in both columns -->
          <td class="displayevens" colspan="2"><button type="button">Display Evens</button></td>
        </tr>
      </form>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I have to allow a user to enter a starting number an ending number and a step value into three textboxes on a page (which I have created). A button will be present that when clicked should output all the even numbers between the start and end value.

My questions are:

1. How does my js code look so far?
2. How do I make a phrase such as: "Here are the even numbers between 4 and 20 by 3's" and then list out the numbers. It will appear once I click the button.

Comment: your js code looks pretty sparse. Where is it?

Comment: if we see the code, we could answer the questions.

Comment: sorry I accidentally clicked post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display all the values inside an array using a button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41403175/display-all-the-values-inside-an-array-using-a-button)

Comment: ^ Exact duplicate of the question

Comment: Your code does not make much sense.

Comment: why do you need step, if you need even numbers?

Answer (score 0):

So it isn't so much that you want the even numbers, you simply want the incremental steps between your starting and ending point. Is that correct? And I assume this is a school assignment? Try something like this to kick you off. I've created the HTML elements, and I've retrieved the values of the inputs. Now you get to create the logic for the increment (try a FOR loop) and insert the results into the progression-pane.

```js
/*****
 * When the "show me!" button gets clicked, 
 *   there's a few things we do: get the values of
 *   the inputs, loop from the starting value to 
 *   the ending value by a given increment (default
 *   increment of two), and output the result to a div.
 *****/
runCounter = function() {
  // This is the location we'll put the result
  var contentPane = document.getElementById("progression-pane");
  // This will be the output string
  var contentString = "";
  
  // retrieve the values given AND MAKE THEM
  //  INTEGERS! We could do floats, but it's 
  //  darn important to make them numbers.
  var startingValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("startingValue").value);
  var endingValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("endingValue").value);
  var increment = parseInt(document.getElementById("incrValue").value);

  if (startingValue && endingValue) {
    // So long as we actually HAVE a staring and ending value...
    if (!increment) increment = 2;
    // If we don't have an increment given, let's count by twos!
    contentString += "<p>The values between " + startingValue + " and " + endingValue + " in increments of " + increment + ":</p><ul>";
    for (i = startingValue; i <= endingValue; i += increment) {
      // If we are here, we have all three: start, end and increment
      contentString += "<li>" + i + "</li>";
    }
    contentString += "</ul>";
    // We've finished formatting the string, 
    //  let's output it to the proper div.
    //  Note that I'm using innerHTML, 
    //   document.writeln is considered bad.
    
    contentPane.innerHTML = contentString;
  }

}
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  }
```

```html
<label for="startingValue">Start:</label>
<input type="text" id="startingValue" />
<label for="endingValue">End:</label>
<input type="text" id="endingValue" />
<label for="startingValue">Increment:</label>
<input type="text" id="incrValue" />
<button onclick="runCounter()">Show me!</button>

<div class="content-pane">
  <h2>Your progression:</h2>
  <div id="progression-pane">
    </div>
  </div>
```

The bulk of the above javascript is actually comments discussing what I'm doing. Get in that habit, so you don't lose track of variables! And yours works fine, but innerHTML is considered better form than document.writeln
Ok, so if in fact you want the EVEN numbers at the given step intervals, change the line that actually appends the line items like this:

```js
       // Now, we want to see if this is an even number
      if(i%2 == 0)
      contentString += "<li>" + i + "</li>";
```

See this version running as a [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/snowMonkey/4enn46ca/)

Comment: I believe the request is for all steps between start and end that `% 2 === 0`

Comment: If that were the case, why is a step interval given?

Comment: i.e. `start = 1; stop = 10; step = 3;` sequence would be `1, 4, 7, 10`, printing only the even numbers in sequence between start & stop would return `4`, if you included the starting/ending numbers, it would return `4,10`. This is obviously not representative of all even numbers between start & stop, which is why the step is important. See the question I tagged this as a duplicate of, they do a better job of explaining what they're trying to accomplish

Comment: And the latest edit does so. The modulo function -- if (i % 2 == 0) -- will only be true for even values. So as I increment by the step, whether odd or even, I can check each step value and only append the appropriate one.

Comment: You should throw a negative check on your increment in addition to your `!increment` check to ensure you don't get an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the values and cast it to number with an unary plus and iterate from starting to ending with the given step. With each loop check if the actual counter is even and add it to the result set.

Later display the result in `results`.

```js
function myarray() {
    var starting = +document.getElementById("starting").value,
        ending = +document.getElementById("ending").value,
        step = +document.getElementById("step").value,
        results = document.getElementById("results"),
        i,
        array = [];
      
    for (i = starting;  i <= ending; i += step) {
        i % 2 || array.push(i);
    }
    results.innerHTML = array.join(', ');
}
```

```html
<pre><form>Starting Number: <input type="text" id="starting"><br>Ending Number:   <input type="text" id="ending"><br>Step:            <input type="text" id="step"><br><button type="button" onclick="myarray()">Display Evens</button></form><div id="results"></div></pre>
```